# Adding hours to a particular day (in Perl)

Tags: perl

I need to add 5hour 30 minutes to whatever the day in format(hh:mm:ss Mmm dd).
 Is there any way in perl to do that?!

Comment: Are you trying to convert Greenwich Mean Time to Indian Standard Time? If your machine time is set to Indian time, you may find you just have to use `localtime` in place of `gmtime`.

Answer (score 8):

Check the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module on the CPAN, in particular the [math methods](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.66/lib/DateTime.pm#Math_Methods).

Comment: And DateTime::Format::Strptime for parsing the input and formatting the output.

Answer (score 5):

What you ask is impossible without knowing the year.  If your time is '18:30:00 Feb 28', should the answer be '00:00:00 Mar 01' or '00:00:00 Feb 29'?